# Reset Session in Microsoft BotFramework with NodeJS

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am working on a simple project where my primary requirement is to use Microsoft BotFramework's WebChat to create a custom inline app. I want to add a button at the  header which will be a reset button, which will restart the session and remove all the messages but will maintain the same conversation ID. I am not finding any useful documentation on how can I send a message to the bot from a button click. Also How can I notify the bot which conversation's session needs to be erased.

This is the sample code I am using,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <link href="stylesheets/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="javascripts/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
     BotChat.App({
       directLine: { secret: '' },
       user: { id: 'you' },
       bot: { id: 'agent' },
       sendTyping: true,
       resize: 'detect'
     }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I have also checked that we have something called **deleteUserData** event, but I am not sure how do I use this in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via back channel. In a nutshell, what will happen is the web page that's hosting webchat will connect to the same DirectLine instance your webchat is using, which will allow the page to communicate with the bot. You can then set up a handler for a reset event which will call the appropriate code to handle resetting the state.

You can see how to set up back channel here:
https://github.com/MissionMarsFourthHorizon/operation-max/tree/master/Node/exercise8-BackChannel

Answer (score 0):

Try [`session.clearDialogStack();`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#cleardialogstack) or [`delete session.userData;`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#userdata)